# Why python unable to take care of pipe with tee utility?

Tags: python, linux, pipe, checksum, tee

I want to run the following command from a python code in a remote machine:

`/bin/cat < abc.txt | tee >(echo $(md5sum) > /tmp/abc.md5sum) | some-other-command`.

I have to use [Cumin](https://cumin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to send this command to remote machines. My code is given below:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process
import os

import cumin
from cumin import query, transport, transports

from mypackage.RemoteExecution import CommandReturn, RemoteExecution


def run_subprocess(host, command, input_pipe):
    e = CuminExecution()
    result = e.run(host, command)
    input_pipe.send(result)


class CuminExecution(RemoteExecution):
    """
    RemoteExecution implementation using Cumin
    """

    def __init__(self, options={}):
        self._config = None
        self.options = options

    @property
    def config(self):
        if not self._config:
            self._config = cumin.Config()

        return self._config

    def format_command(self, command):
        if isinstance(command, str):
            return command
        else:
            return ' '.join(command)

    def run(self, host, command):
        hosts = query.Query(self.config).execute(host)
        if not hosts:
            return CommandReturn(1, None, 'host is wrong or does not match rules')
        target = transports.Target(hosts)
        worker = transport.Transport.new(self.config, target)
        worker.commands = [self.format_command(command)]
        worker.handler = 'sync'

        return_code = worker.execute()

        for nodes, output in worker.get_results():
            if host in nodes:
                result = str(bytes(output), 'utf-8')
                return CommandReturn(return_code, result, None)

        return CommandReturn(return_code, None, None)

    def start_job(self, host, command):
        output_pipe, input_pipe = Pipe()
        job = Process(target=run_subprocess, args=(host, command, input_pipe))
        job.start()
        input_pipe.close()
        return {'process': job, 'pipe': output_pipe}

    def monitor_job(self, host, job):
        if job['process'].is_alive():
            return CommandReturn(None, None, None)
        else:
            result = job['pipe'].recv()
            job['pipe'].close()
            return result

    def kill_job(self, host, job):
        if job['process'].is_alive():
            job['process'].terminate()

    def wait_job(self, host, job):
        job['process'].join()
        result = job['pipe'].recv()
        job['pipe'].close()
        return result


src_command = "/bin/cat < abc.txt | tee >(echo $(md5sum) > /tmp/abc.md5sum) | some-other-command"
result = CuminExecution.run(host, src_command)
```

When I run the command `/bin/cat < abc.txt | tee >(echo $(md5sum) > /tmp/abc.md5sum) | some-other-command` from the terminal, it is working as expected. But when I try to run it using python3 using the above code, It can process all the commands properly except the writing to `/tmp/abc.md5sum` part! After the run, the file abc.md5sum contains an incorrect hash.

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: How exactly do you execute this from Python? You are probably using a shell that doesn't support process substitution.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your comment, I am using `/bin/bash -c` to specify it as a bash shell

Comment: How, exactly? Please post actual Python code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @chepner I have updated my code, Could you please have a look now?

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your help! I have tried with different command and it is working for me now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the command this way:

`/bin/cat < abc.txt | tee >(md5sum > /tmp/abc.md5sum) | some-other-command`

and it is working now! Thank you all for your help!